# Proper Class Modeling using C++ and const

Tags: c++, constants

Let me preference that I mostly develop in C# and the C++ development which I have done did not fully leverage the C++ language.  I am now trying to use the language as it was intended and I am pulling my hair out with const declarations in passed arguments.  In the past I never used them or hacked my way into making them work with the STL.

My understanding that I would create the following function when I want to use o as readonly in the function:

```
void foo(const MyClass* o);
```

So here is my problem...code first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Classes are defined in the one file for an easy post.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class ClassA {
private: // member variables
    string m_name;

public: // constructors
    ClassA(const string& name = "") : m_name{name} {}
    virtual ~ClassA() { }

public: // accessors
    const string& name() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(const string& value) { m_name = value; }   
};

class ClassB {
private: // member variables
    string m_name;
    ClassA m_child;

public: // constructors
    ClassB(const string& name = "") : m_name{name} {}
    virtual ~ClassB() { }

public: // accessors
    const string& name() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(const string& value) { m_name = value; }

    ClassA* child() { return &m_child; }
    void setChild(const ClassA* value) { m_child = *value; }
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Protoptypes are not used to save space for the post.

void doSomethingA(const ClassA* o) {
   cout << "name = " << o->name() << endl << endl;
}

void doSomethingB(const ClassB* o) {
   cout << "name = " << o->name() << endl << endl;
   doSomethingA(o->child());
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ClassA a { "My Class A" };
    ClassB b { "My Class B" };


    b.setChild(&a);
    b.child()->setName("My New Name");
    doSomethingB(&b);
    return 0;
}
```

In main() the compiler (g++ version 4.7.2) balks in doSomethingB:

```
doSomethingA(o->child());
```

with error: passing 'const ClassB' as 'this' argument of 'ClassA* ClassB::child()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Now I am passing my classes to functions as pointers.  I plan on always using pointers because I have a problem with the reference/pointer options.  I'm choosing one, pointers, and sticking with it.  So doSomethingA and doSomethingB I want that to be const to tell the programmer that their class is not being altered.  But I only want one version of child() which I want to use sometimes as "read only" and other times allow the user to change the data within the child object (not the best method, I grant that, but there are some use cases where I need this).  I even tried:

```
doSomethingA(const_cast<const ClassA*>(o->child()));
```

But that did not work.

In the past I removed the const declarations in the functions to make something like this work but now I want to use proper c++.  Help please.

Comment: Have you tried making the `child()` function `const`?

Comment: "I plan on always using pointers because I have a problem with the reference/pointer options." just buys you a heap of problems. don't do that.

Comment: If you just use pointers, you have to constantly check for null pointers.  If you use references, no.  So the simple rule is: if you want to support null pointers, use pointers, otherwise references.  Using pointers everywhere means that you'll never be able to pass a temporary.

Comment: Note, this problem would not have occurred if you used the language as it was intended (references)

Comment: nullptr is good if used properly.  I'm use to that with C# and null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to access a non-const function against a const object. You need to make the function `const` :

```
const ClassA* child() const { return &m_child; }
```

You can also provide a const and non-const version:

```
ClassA* child() { return &m_child; }
const ClassA* child() const { return &m_child; }
```

This way you can call non-const methods on `ClassA` when you have a non-const object.

Comment: Notably, this isn't necessary if he used references instead of pointers

Comment: Same problem with references. I did not know you could do that.  I thought that followed the rule where you cannot overload a function with the only difference being the return type. Like int foo(); and double foo(); are not allowed.  What I now don't understand is int foo() and const int foo() are also not allowed.  Why is it different as a member function.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ClassA* child() const { return &m_child; }
```

or

```
const ClassA* child() const { return &m_child; }
```

to keep the const correctness

Also, you don't need to use pointers as long as you don't plan passing nullptr. So you can do the following:

```
void doSomethingB(const ClassB& o);

// in class ClassB
const ClassA& child() const { return m_child; }
ClassA& child() { return m_child; }
```

References still alow polymorphic stuff same way as pointers.

Comment: The return type would have to be a `const` pointer too. For other parts of the OP's code to work, `child` would have to be overloaded on `const`.